# gradle build failure Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused

Tags: build, gradle, proxy

I am trying to build a sample project that is included in gradle distribution. When I do `gradle build` I get this error:

```
Could not resolve commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1.
Required by:
    :application:1.0.2
 > Could not HEAD 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.pom'.
    > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
```

I work behind a proxy. I tried the things mentioned here:
[gradle documentation for proxy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single#N11899) but I get the same error.
Can you help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add gradle.properties file next to the .gradle file with this content :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost 

systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Comment: You may need to add systemProp.http.proxyUser=my_user_name
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=my_secret_password ... 
systemProp.https.proxyUser=my_user_name
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=my_secret_password.　Also, for a Windows machine the gradle.properties file is in C:\Documents and Settings\myAccount\.gradle\gradle.properties.  And check that you have  a “GRADLE_USER_HOME” environment variable pointing to C:\Documents and Settings\myAccount\.gradle